# Problema con IIf y '[']'

Tags: vba, ms-access

En una caja de texto de un formulario, se puede meter un código sólo con caracteres normales o bien caracteres seguidos de otro código entre corchetes: [xxxxxxx]. Dependiendo del tipo de entrada, hay que devolver una cadena u otra.

Si la cadena lleva corchetes, éstos se eliminan. Si no los lleva, da error, porque los busca igualmente. El objetivo es conseguir que esto no pase.
En la parte principal del programa, tengo:

```
If Me!Proveedor = "BIMBO" Then
Me!NombreProducto = Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Mid(Me!Producto, InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")) - (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")) - 1)), 50)
```

La función a la que llama tiene como argumentos:

```
BuscaNombre(ByVal Tipo As String, ByVal Codigo As String) As String
```

El valor de Producto, que es una caja de texto que está en el formulario activo, es en este caso "zxc". Lo que creo que pasa con este código es que al usar el Mid, el inStr y demás para dar valor al argumento, si en la cadena de entrada no encuentra símbolos del tipo [ o ] que son los que parece estar buscando, da error.

Si esta hipótesis es correcta, ¿Cómo se podría solucionar para que en el caso que no hubiera símbolos de entrada, el código entrara correctamente en la función?

Una posible solución es ésta:

```
Me!NombreProducto = iif(InStr(1, Me!Producto, "["), Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Mid(Me!Producto, InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[") + 1, (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")) - (InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")) - 1)), 50), Left(BuscaNombre("BIMBO", Me!Producto.text), 50)
```

Pero no funciona, el editor de texto de VBA Access da error. ¿Alguien tiene una pista de por qué?

Comment: Quizás sería más fácil simplemente comprobar si tiene corchetes con un `If InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")>0 or InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")>0 Then...  ` y dividir lo que quieres que haga.

Comment: Sí! Esa es la solución, lo hemos probado y funciona bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución sería dividir el IF según haya corchetes o no:

```
If InStr(1, Me!Producto, "[")>0 or InStr(1, Me!Producto, "]")>0 Then
'hacer algo si hay corchetes
Else
'hacer otra cosa cuando no hay corchetes
End If
```